# Selecting from a pandas Series where the labels are tuples

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do the following:

```
In [11]: import itertools

In [12]: states = itertools.product(range(2), range(3))

In [13]: s = pd.Series(np.zeros(6), index=states)

In [14]: s.at[(0, 0)]
```

where `pd` and `np` are `pandas` and `numpy`, respectively. However, this leads to a

> ValueError: At based indexing on an non-integer index can only have non-integer indexers

I can't figure out from http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/indexing.html what is wrong with this; as I understand it, `.at` is equivalent to `.loc` when selecting a single value, and here I'm passing the tuple `(0, 0)` as the index. How can I get this to work? (I'd prefer to use pandas' optimized methods `at`/`loc` instead of the `__getitem__` methods).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion here is better use `MultiIndex` and select by `loc`:

```
import itertools
states = list(itertools.product(range(2), range(3)))
s = pd.Series(range(6), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(states))

print (s)
0  0    0
   1    1
   2    2
1  0    3
   1    4
   2    5
dtype: int32

print (s.loc[(0, 0)])
0
```

EDIT:

And better solution with commnt of OP using [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
s = pd.Series(range(6), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(2), range(3)]))
print (s)
0  0    0
   1    1
   2    2
1  0    3
   1    4
   2    5
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Nice! Following https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html one can also define `s` using `MultiIndex.from_product`: `s = pd.Series(range(6), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(2), range(3)]))`, and dispense with `itertools.product`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is better.

Answer (score 2):

dirty hack:

```
In [43]: s.loc[[(0,0)]].iat[0]
Out[43]: 0.0
```